# SQLAlchemy parent to own instance

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a noob in databases so please help me. I'm trying to implement a filesystem for my api. I already have the user and the files related to each other, now I'm trying to implement a directory hierarchy for the files. My thought was that I add a directory row to the database which holds the information about its parent dir, the child dirs and the files in it. My first approach was to do this (without the files first):

```
class Directory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship('Directory', back_populates='parent')
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Directory', db.back_populates='children')
```

This is what I was thinking of after reading [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) tutorial. But I don't think this is right nor that this is the right approach.

Any ideas on how to implement this are welcome :)

Comment: [Seems like what you need](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to [@Fian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7324965/fian) for the [solution](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html). I'm going to post the answer for my case here:

```
class Directory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('directory.id'))
    children = db.relationship('Directory',
                backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
            )
    files = db.relationship('File', backref='dir', lazy='dynamic')

class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    dir_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('directory.id'))
```

If the link gets invalid this is called `Adjacency List Relationships`